# What is the LaTeX equivalent of setting \uchyph=1?

Tags: hyphenation

If I understand correcly, when using LaTeX rather than Plain TeX, one should avoid using primitives directly and instead use `\newcommand`, `\setlength`, etc.

Therefore, I think that my habit of setting `\uchyph=1` as the first line of my document is not idiomatic. What would be the LaTeX way of preventing line breaks for words starting with a capital letter (especially acronyms and surnames)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\uchyph=1` is the latex syntax.

LaTeX doesn't have any higher level syntax for setting any TeX integer primitive.

While this answers the direct question, 1 is the LaTeX default value, so you could simply delete the setting.

`\uchyph=1` *allows* hyphenation if the starting letter is uppercase

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\showhyphens{football Football FOOTBALL}

\uchyph=0
\showhyphens{football Football FOOTBALL}

\uchyph=1
\showhyphens{football Football FOOTBALL}


\end{document}
```

Produces

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 5--5
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 foot-ball Foot-ball FOOT-BALL

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 8--8
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 foot-ball Football FOOTBALL

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 11--11
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 foot-ball Foot-ball FOOT-BALL
```

showing that it is

```
\uchyph=0
```

that is needed to suppress hyphens.